# How do I join a Terraria server?

Tags: terraria

I need to join a Terraria server in multiplayer (https://terraria-servers.com/server/650/) but when I enter the server port (7777), and click accept, it doesn't do anything. Nothing happens at all. Can somebody help?

Comment: Wrong adress and port, just connect via this: t.teeria.eu:7776 the actual adress in your link

Answer (score 0):

A server address can be separated into two portions: the IP address/domain name (domain names are translated back to IP addresses) and the port number, separated by a colon (`:`). In your case, the server address is `t.teeria.eu:7776`, therefore you should enter `t.teeria.eu` for the domain name first, then `7776` for the port number (instead of the default `7777`).

Answer (score 0):

First, you must use the t.teeria.eu part in the first part, then it will ask for the ip address, in which you type in 7776, or 7777 by default.